# How to show an icon and underline effect when hovering over text

Tags: css, angular

I created an effect in the CSS content. When the user hovers the mouse over the text, a line appears as if it were an underline that increases when the mouse hovers over it, and decreases when the user takes the mouse off the text.

The problem is that I would like to show an icon next to this text and that when the underline appears and disappears, the icon appears. If I put display: block, the underline effect when hovering the mouse over it doesn't happen. How can I resolve this?

CSS:

```css
/* You can add global styles to this file, and also import other style files */
.navbar {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    align-items: flex-start;
    padding: 0px;
    gap: 40px;
    position: absolute;
    width: 639.98px;
    height: 32px;
    left: 363px;
    top: 72px;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    box-shadow: 0px 4px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25), 0px 4px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
    padding-top: 72px;
}

.sobre {
    width: 108.1px;
    height: 32px;
    flex: none;
    order: 0;
    flex-grow: 0;
    color: white;
    font-family: 'Outfit', sans-serif;

    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 900;
    font-size: 20.7558px;
    line-height: 28px;
    text-decoration: none;
    position: relative;

    /* Grad horizontal */

    background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(251, 62, 107, 0.95) 10%, #8F00FF 91.6%);
    background-size: 40% 3px;
    background-position: left bottom;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    transition: background-size 300ms ease;
}

.sobreImg {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    left: 110px;
    top: 2px;
    visibility: hidden;
}

.sobreImg:hover {
    display: block;
    visibility: visible;
}

.sobre:hover {
    background-size: 100% 3px;
}
```

HTML:

```html
<nav class="navbar">
  <!--  <a class="home" routerLink="/">home</a> -->
  <a class="ferramentas" routerLink="/">ferramentas
    <img src="../assets/icones/ferramentas.svg" class="ferramentasImg">
  </a>
  <a class="contato" routerLink="/">contato
    <img src="../assets/icones/contato.svg" class="contatoImg">
  </a>
  <a class="projetos" routerLink="/">projetos
    <img src="../assets/icones/projetos.svg" class="projetosImg">
  </a>
  <a class="sobre" routerLink="/">sobre mim
    <img src="../assets/icones/sobremim.svg" class="sobreImg">
  </a>
  <a class="skills" routerLink="/">soft skills
    <img src="../assets/icones/soft.svg" class="softImg">
  </a>

</nav>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

Comment: You can combine ::after and ::before pseudo-elements with hover.

Additional information about ::after you can learn here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::after

Answer (score 0):

You could try styling the icons on hover of the parent anchor tag using a [child combinator selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Child_combinator) in combination with the `:hover` pseudo selector like: `.navlink:hover > .navlinkImg`.

**NOTE** I adjusted your HTML and CSS slightly to be more reusable, e.g. used a common `.navlink` class for the `<a />` tags and added `.navlinkImg` to the icons within each link.

```css
/* You can add global styles to this file, and also import other style files */
.navbar {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    align-items: flex-start;
    padding: 0px;
    gap: 40px;
    position: absolute;
    width: 639.98px;
    height: 32px;
    left: 363px;
    top: 72px;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    box-shadow: 0px 4px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25), 0px 4px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
    padding-top: 72px;
}

.navlink {
    display: flex;
    width: 108.1px;
    height: 32px;
    flex: none;
    order: 0;
    flex-grow: 0;
    color: white;
    font-family: 'Outfit', sans-serif;

    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 900;
    font-size: 20.7558px;
    line-height: 28px;
    text-decoration: none;
    position: relative;


    /* grad horizontal */
    background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(251, 62, 107, 0.95) 10%, #8F00FF 91.6%);
    background-size: 40% 3px;
    background-position: left bottom;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    transition: background-size 300ms ease;
}

.navlink:hover {
    background-size: 100% 3px;
}

.navlink:hover > .navlinkImg {
  display: block;
  visibility: visible;
}

.navlinkImg {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<nav class="navbar">
  <!--  <a class="home" routerLink="/">home</a> -->
  <a class="navlink ferramentas" routerLink="/">ferramentas
    <img src="../assets/icones/ferramentas.svg" class="navlinkImg ferramentasImg">
  </a>
  <a class="navlink contato" routerLink="/">contato
    <img src="../assets/icones/contato.svg" class="navlinkImg contatoImg">
  </a>
  <a class="navlink projetos" routerLink="/">projetos
    <img src="../assets/icones/projetos.svg" class="navlinkImg projetosImg">
  </a>
  <a class="navlink sobre" routerLink="/">sobre mim
    <img src="../assets/icones/sobremim.svg" class="navlinkImg sobreImg">
  </a>
  <a class="navlink skills" routerLink="/">soft skills
    <img src="../assets/icones/soft.svg" class="navlinkImg softImg">
  </a>
</nav>
```

Comment: thank you so much! It worked! I will study more about pseudo-selector